# lubuntu: alias application-specific initialization failed: file open failed

Tags: ubuntu, alias

i'm using lubuntu(ubuntu) an have a problem with the alias function when i want to open xampp.
when i type

```
sudo /opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run
```

it works fine.

when i create an alias with:

```
alias xampp='/opt/lampp/manager-linux-x64.run'
```

and then type "xampp" i get an error:

```
application-specific initialization failed: file open failed
```

so i'm pretty new to linux and have no idea why this appear and i couldn't find my problem by search.

Comment: This is probably a better question for Super User, since it isn't really a programming problem.

Comment: ok,thank you i didn't know that something like superuser exists :)